# STM32F7 + FatFs = FR_NOT_READY

Tags: stm32, stm32f7, fatfs, cubemx

I am now using CubeMx 4.23.0 and FW package for STM32F7 1.8.0
MCU is STM32F746 on Core746i board.
Everything is generated by CubeMx automatically.

main.c:

```
    SCB_EnableICache();
    SCB_EnableDCache();
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    MX_FATFS_Init();

    HAL_Delay(3000);
    DebugString("start OK");

    uint8_t res = 0;
    FATFS SDFatFs;  
    FIL MyFile;     /* File object */
    char SD_Path[4]; 

    res = f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*)SD_Path, 0);
    sprintf(DebugStr, "f_mount = 0x%02X", res);
    DebugString(DebugStr);

    res = f_open(&MyFile, "test.txt", FA_READ);
    sprintf(DebugStr, "f_open = 0x%02X", res);
    DebugString(DebugStr);
```

sdmmc.c:

```
void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void)
    {

      hsd1.Instance = SDMMC1;
      hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
      hsd1.Init.ClockBypass = SDMMC_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
      hsd1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
      hsd1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_1B;
      hsd1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
      hsd1.Init.ClockDiv = 7;

   //HAL_SD_Init(&hsd1);
   // ^^^^^ I also tried this here
   //HAL_SD_ConfigWideBusOperation(&hsd1, SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_4B)
   //^^^^ and this
            }
```

In case of f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*)SD_Path, 0) <- with 1 here (forced mount), output is:

> 1. f_mount = 0x03
> 2. f_open = 0x01

With 0 (do not mount now) output is:

> 1. f_mount = 0x00
> 2. f_open = 0x03

0x03 value is FR_NOT_READY, but official info is pretty vague about it

Things I've tried:

> 1. Adding HAL_SD_Init(&hsd1) to MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init() since i didnt find where is SD card GPIO init happening.
> 2. 2 GB noname SD card, 1 GB Transcend card.
> 3. Different hsd1.Init.ClockDiv 3 to 255.
> 4. Resoldering everything completely.
> 5. Switching to 4-bit wide bus using HAL_SD_ConfigWideBusOperation(&hsd1, SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_4B);
> 6. Turn on and off pullups.

But card still does not mount. It's formatted in FAT, working on a PC, files i've tried to open are exist, but empty.

How to get it to mount?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Files you tried opening exist? Does "test.txt" exist? Even if the mount failed? You're receiving FR_NOT_READY  because 1. The hardware level has issues, check if FAT-FS pins are mapped 2. No FAT found. But you say you've already checked these. Please try mount like f_mount(fs, "", 0);   i.e mount with path as the root path. I'm not sure about you passing a null char array.

Comment: Check hardware maps in code. Test f_mount(fs, "", 0); if this too fails theres something wrong with your hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was the problem with exact version of cubemx. 
updating stm32cubemx helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can  try

> `f_mount(0, "path", 0);

` after the f_open call . it may work.
If the function with forced mounting failed with FR_NOT_READY, it means that the filesystem object has been registered successfully but the

> volume is currently not ready to work

. The volume mount process will be attempted on subsequent file/directroy function.

If implementation of the disk I/O layer lacks asynchronous media change detection, application program needs to perform f_mount function after each media change to force cleared the filesystem object.

Answer (score 0):

Changing all SDIO pins except SDIO_CK to pull-up according to [This Topic](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWceSAF/stm32f411re-stm32cube-fatfs-sdio-sdcard-always-returns-frdiskerr?t=1573717870396) works for me

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting `MX_USB_DEVICE_Init()`, see what happens.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why might this solve the problem?

Comment: How will this fix the issue? USB and FATFS are totally unrelated! As it was generated using CubeMX OP might have not configured the SPI pins properly.